# I cant go to the page it says page not found

Tags: laravel

Is there something wrong in my route in index? What should I do? I'm just starting to learn laravel.

web.php
[image]
myController
[image]

index.blade.php
[image]

Comment: Your not specifying a index on your controller. Your returning a welcome view for /.

Comment: Please add your code as text rather than screen shots. It helps others trying to reproduce your problem and help out.

Answer (score 0):

which function you want to route in myController?

. For example, you may access the following route by navigating to  http://localhost/ in your browser:

```
Route::get('/', 'myController@index'); //myController-indexfunction
```

read [laravel routing doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing)

Comment: then u have to pass $id to the edit function and route will be like that  Route::get('/{id}', 'myController@edit');

Comment: what if in my database i name my id as no.

Comment: you should read laravel documentation first and test laravel sample project first before asking like this.your question need too much detail and I cant tell you all.